# Find probability using geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I wanted someone to check the solution of this problem (see Rice's book, problem 2.14)

Two boys play basketball in the following way. They take turns shooting and
stop when a basket is made. Player A goes first and has probability $p_1$ of making a basket on any throw. Player B, who shoots second, has probability $p_2$ of making a basket. The outcomes of the successive trials are assumed to be independent.

**a.** Find the frequency function for the total number of attempts.

**b.** What is the probability that player A wins?

My solution: 
**a.** suppose that they make $k$ attempts. Then the answer depends on parity of $k$. If $k=2n+1$ it means that first player made $n+1$ attempts and $n$ first attempts were unsuccessful, while the last one was successful (he made a basket). As for second player, he made $n$ unsuccessful attempts. 
Bot these probabilities are easily found by multiplication of respective probabilities for the first and second player.

The case when $k$ is even is solved in a similar way.

**b.** According to part a., we know how to find the probability that the game is over at $2n+1$ attempt. Therefore we sum these probabilities over $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Is it correct? Would be appreciated for your tips!

Comment: The idea is right.  The distribution is not geometric in general.

Comment: Thanks, André! I just wanted to give it some relevant title. I want to ask experienced users here: Is it OK if I post some problems along with their solutions here? I just want to check if my reasonings have any flaws

Comment: I think it is OK.  But what is above might be considered too unspecific for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with enumerating all the paths and then summing the probabilities.  Another approach, which is sometimes simpler algebraically, is to do it recursively:

Let $P(p_1,p_2)$ be the probability A wins given the data you mention.  Let's say A takes one shot.  It goes in, with probability $p_1$ and misses with probability $1-p_1$  If it misses, you are in back at the start of a similar game...only now Player B shoots first and the probability that A wins from here is 1 - $P(p_2,p_1)$.  Thus $$P(p_1,p_2) = p_1 + (1-p_1)(1 - P(p_2,p_1))$$
A similar calculation shows that 
$$P(p_2,p_1) = p_2 + (1-p_2)(1 - P(p_1,p_2))$$
In this way we get two equations in two unknowns which can easily be solved to yield $$P(p_1,p_2) = \frac{p_1}{p_1-p_1p_2 + p_2}$$
(trusting that no algebraic error was made).  As a sanity check, if we assume both probabilities are $\frac 12$, as in the case of alternating coin tosses, then this becomes $\frac 23$ which is the familiar answer.

Comment: Problem that I see with this solution: $$P(p_1,p_2)=\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$$ and $$P(p_2,p_1)=\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}.$$ Then $$P(p_1,p_2)+P(p_2,p_1)=\frac{p_1+p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}\not = 1$$

The events whose probabilities are given here cannot be mutually exclusive. I would expect that either the first player wins or the second player wins, both of them cannot win. Please explain.

Comment: @zoli  You are reading it wrong.  P($p_2$,$p_1$) IS NOT the probability that Player B will win the given competition.  Rather it is the probability that Player B would win the competition if he got to start first!  there is no reason why they should add to 1.  In the coin flipping case, P($p_2$,$p_1$) = P($p_1$,$p_2$) = $\frac23$ for example.

Comment: To further illustrate...if $p_1$ = 1 then the formula tells you that P($p_1$,$p_2$)  = 1 regardless of the value of $p_2$.  This is correct!  Player A should always win.  On the other hand, if B started then the formula for P($p_2$,$p_1$)  correctly gives $p_2$ as his chances....he gets one shot!  Again the two probabilities correctly add over 1 without a contradiction.

Comment: OK, I understand. In the pain of struggling with your clever solution I went back to the brute force method and gave the primitive solution.

Comment: Nor is the direct computation (I wouldn't call it primitive!) all that bad.  I think I am betraying my bias a bit...I seldom expect to be able to enumerate all the winning paths so I don't even look for that.

Answer (score 0):

Odd number of attempts ending with success results that the first player wins with probability
$$p_1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(1-p_1)(1-p_2)]^n=\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}.$$

So, the probability that the second player wins is $1$ minus the probability above:

$$\frac{p_2(1-p_1)}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}.$$

Or, one can say that if the number of attempts ending with a success is even then the second player wins. The probability of this event is

$$p_2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p_1)^n(1-p_2)^{n-1}=p_2(1-p_1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(1-p_1)(1-p_2)]^n=\frac{p_2(1-p_1)}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}.$$